# Is the function $f: (1, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-x}$ continuous ?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Is the function $f: (1, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-x}$ continuous ? I know that for each

$n \ge 1$ , the function $g:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb R ; g(x)=n^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous . So for a given $\epsilon >0 , a \in (1,\infty) , n \ge 1 , \exists \delta_{\epsilon,n}$ such that $|x-a|<\delta _{\epsilon , n} \implies |n^{-x}-n^{-a}|<\dfrac \epsilon{2^n}$ but if we then want to sum over $n$ , to make each $\epsilon /2^n$ estimate valid , we have to take

$\max\{\delta_{\epsilon , n} : n \ge 1\}$ which may not exist as we are taking maximum over a set which we don't know is finite or not . So I am stuck . Please help .

Comment: This function is called Riemann's Zeta function, and it is continuous (in fact, it is $C^{\infty}$).

Answer (score 0):

For every $b>a>1$ let the functions $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f_n=n^{-x}$, then these functions are all continuous on $[a,b]$ and are bounded by $\frac1{n^a}$ on $[a,b]$, so by [Weierstrass's M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) for [uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) of series, and by convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^a}$ we find out that the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^x}$ is continuous on every closed sub interval of $(1,\infty)$ and so continuous on the whole of interval!