Prove function defined by series is continuous
I am working on this problem. I am studying for an exam. I find it hard to believe this has not been asked before, but I could not find it.
Show that the function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$ is continuous for $x > 1$.
My attempt at a solution is the following. By the density of the reals, there exists an $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $1 < 1 + \epsilon < x$ for all $x > 1$. Then, for all $n \geq 1$, we have that $\frac{1}{n^x} \leq \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$. And by the integral test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. Thus, by the Weierstrass $M$-test, the given series converges uniformly and hence $f$ is continuous because $\frac{1}{n^x}$ is continuous for all $n$. Is this correct? Even if it is, there must be a better way of doing this. Any help is appreciated.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223648/1118406

@SineoftheTime You found it. Thanks. It's the same solution but written better.
